# In node Express project, how to access a javascript library from within a controller within an MVC framework

Tags: node.js, express

I have a controllers folder in my node Express project. I have installed Axios via npm and required it in my app.js file. I need to access Axios from within my controller. I can do so by requiring it again at the top of my controller file but I was wondering if this is the correct way of doing so. In my app.js file after requiring axios I have have tried

```
  app.use(axios)
```

and

```
    app.use((req , res , next){
res.locals.axios = axios;
next()
)
```

But neither of these functions work. So I am back to requiring Axios from the controller, which does work but doesnt seem like the best method. Below is my controller

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.home = (req , res) => {
    res.render('index' , {
        title : 'Check the weather in your town'
    })
}

exports.getWeather = function (req, res) {
    let city = req.body.city;
    console.log(city)
    axios.all([
      axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2017-08-03'),
      axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2017-08-02')
    ]).then(axios.spread((response1, response2) => {
      console.log(response1.data.url);
      console.log(response2.data.url);
    })).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    res.redirect('/')
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you are over thinking this.

Node's require does magic and using caching to help reduce overhead for requiring modules into files.  Don't worry about requiring the same module in a few different files.

Even if you could get this to work you have to consider a few other things.

- How would you test it? There are loads of testing frameworks that help you override requires to help with unit testing.  You would likely have to homebrew something in case 1.
- Are all of your endpoints going to use `axios`?  What if as you grow you have other endpoints that dont need it.  Now you would be forcing it in.
- Where does it end?  If there was another require would you also pass that through `app.js`?
- Having the require where you use it make it more maintainable.  When you come back and look at this in two months will you be confused about where `axios` is coming from?

tl;dr: Requiring Axios from the controller is the best method

Comment: Thank you for your time. You have set my mind at ease, I just wasn't sure I wasn't bloating my code unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MindlessRouse answer. If you really want to, create a function, passing axios as an argument then return the middleware function using axios:

```
exports.getWeather = function(axios){
    return function (req, res) {
        let city = req.body.city;
        console.log(city)
        axios.all([
          axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2017-08-03'),
          axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&date=2017-08-02')
        ]).then(axios.spread((response1, response2) => {
          console.log(response1.data.url);
          console.log(response2.data.url);
        })).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
        res.redirect('/')
    };
}
```

You can then mount the function in express app like this:

```
   const controller = require('controller.js');
   ...
   app.use( controller.getWeather(axios) );
```